# How to mock out Thread.sleep() with JMockit?

Tags: static-methods, junit4, jmockit

I have the following code:

```
class Sleeper {
    public void sleep(long duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I test, with JMockit, that Thread.currentThread().interrupt() is called if Thread.sleep() throws an InterruptedException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. A bit tricky to test because mocking certain methods of `java.lang.Thread` can interfere with the JRE or with JMockit itself, and because JMockit is (currently) unable to *dynamically* mock native methods such as `sleep`. That said, it can still be done:

```
public void testResetInterruptStatusWhenInterrupted() throws Exception
{
    new Expectations() {
       @Mocked({"sleep", "interrupt"}) final Thread unused = null;

       {
           Thread.sleep(anyLong); result = new InterruptedException();
           onInstance(Thread.currentThread()).interrupt();
       }
    };

    new Sleeper.sleep();
}
```

Comment: Small comment with an update as it now (jmockit 1.28, but probably starting some versions before) looks different (taken/inspired from/by the JREMockingTest.java sample of JMockit):
`@Test
   public void callThreadSleepOnceSomewhere(@Mocked Thread unused) throws Exception
   {
      new Expectations() {{
         Thread.sleep(anyLong); times = 1;
      }};
      // your code calling Thread.sleep(...) once
}`

Answer (score 1):

### As of JMockit 1.43, this is impossible

JMockit 1.43 added [this commit](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/commit/72ed4d01a92ae15b74b4568ec7a7deeeca6ae361), which checks if you are trying to mock a thread and blacklists it. Now you will get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Thread is not mockable